# Why my formula is showing error - Inconsistent calculated column formula in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

My formula is showing error: **Inconsistent calculated column formula**. But still its working and returning result as expected.

Formula:

```
=IF(B7="","",IF((MINUTE(M7))>=15,TRUNC(HOUR(M7)+MINUTE(M7)/60)+1,TRUNC(HOUR(M7)+MINUTE(M7)/60)))
```

I'm using Microsoft Office 2007. Please help.

Comment: Doesn't this just mean that this formula is different from other formulas in the same column ? Can you check if this formula is consistent with those above and below it ?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the formula on the previous row/column is a bit different. 
[This is what Microsoft says about it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-calculated-columns-in-an-Excel-table-873fbac6-7110-4300-8f6f-aafa2ea11ce8):

> *Calculated columns in Excel tables are a fantastic tool for entering formulas efficiently. They allow you to enter a single formula in one cell, and then that formula will automatically expand to the rest of the column by itself. There’s no need to use the Fill or Copy commands. This can be incredibly time saving, especially if you have a lot of rows. And the same thing happens when you change a formula; the change will also expand to the rest of the calculated column. 
>   A calculated column can include a cell that has a different formula from the rest. This creates an exception that will be clearly marked in the table. This way, inadvertent inconsistencies can easily be detected and resolved.*

[image]

Comment: @AmlanDutta - if you want a different formula than the one next to your cell - then yes.

Comment: Since it is a column formula, you shouldn't get this error if all the formulas in the column are consistent. But sometimes even if they all seem the same, they don't match what Excel thinks is the real column formula. Usually you have to delete all the formulas in the column, then reenter the formula you want in the first row, and let it autofill.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to have different formulas in the same column in a table, you can turn off this "annoying" feature of excel globally as shown below.  I wish I could turn it off, per table or at least per sheet.

under Excel Options / Formulas

[image]