# Why does Excel Table keep including the last added row and how to solve this?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table that looks like below:
[image]

The transaction Amount is inputted manually.

The problem is, if I want to add something new in the last row, Excel keeps on including the last row like this:
[image]
See the formula in R4? There's a green arrow in the left side of the cell and it said "Inconsistent calculated formula" and proceeded to include the last row (5), instead of (4) in R4. I have tried unchecking the option for excel autocorrect option and it still doesn't work.

Anybody knows how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the formatting of that cell?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Right click the cell with the green arrow and see what formatting is assigned.  It should be a number and not text.  You could do the same for the other rows in that column to see what they have been formatted to.

Comment: One other thing I noticed is you have E2,E2  E3,E3  E5,E4  E5,E5. The third set should probably be E4,E4.

Comment: That's exactly the problem I am asking. Excel keeps changing it automatically. I am showing it as a formula to make it clearer.

Comment: What is the reason for the green arrow in row 3 1st column? Row 2 has an '1' and row 3 a '-'. –

Comment: it said "inconsistent calculated formula"

Comment: Any luck yet?  Try this:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fix-an-inconsistent-formula-5dd940a1-4f87-44bd-91dd-bf45ed828f05  and check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886973/why-my-formula-is-showing-error-inconsistent-calculated-column-formula-in-ms-e

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Jeffrey, but I think I will use Tom's suggestion first and see how it goes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just change the formula in column R so that it's the same across all rows? Possibly using something like this:

```
=IFERROR(IF[@[Invoice ID]]="","",[@[Total Value]]-SUMIFS([Transaction Amount],[Invoice ID],[@[Invoice ID]],[Date],"<="&[@Date])),"")
```

Comment: yeah I will try using your way to solve this. Right now it seems the best solution. Thanks!